# Webscraping data from collapsible table returning empty frame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape COVID cases from here:
https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html

If you click on the "+" next to "States" below the map, you'll see the count of cases for each state. I want a dataframe that looks like this from each state

```
Alabama         1841
Alaska          185
American Samoa  0
```

With my attempt, containers is empty

```
my_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "rt-td"})
```

I understand I'll need to loop through to get the info for each state but I need help getting the basic code to work. This is my first attempt at webscraping; I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong tags or findAll arguments. I've tried a couple of different combination and none work.

I found a lady who did something similar to what I want here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/scrape-cdc-for-covid-19-cases-a162924073ad

But she's a developer I think and her skills are above mine. There has to be a much simpler way to do this. Right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is far better way here. the data is returned as a json response. Simply pull the json, then use pandas to normalize it.

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url="https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/map-cases-us.json"
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

df = json_normalize(jsonData['data'])
df = df[['Jurisdiction', 'Cases Reported']].dropna()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
            Jurisdiction  Cases Reported
0                Alabama          1841.0
1                 Alaska           185.0
2         American Samoa             0.0
3                Arizona          2269.0
4               Arkansas           853.0
5             California         13438.0
6               Colorado          4950.0
7            Connecticut          5675.0
8               Delaware           673.0
9   District of Columbia           998.0
10               Florida         11961.0
11               Georgia          6752.0
12                  Guam           110.0
13                Hawaii           324.0
14                 Idaho          1101.0
15              Illinois         11256.0
16               Indiana          4411.0
17                  Iowa           868.0
18                Kansas           813.0
19              Kentucky           955.0
20             Louisiana         13010.0
21                 Maine           470.0
22      Marshall Islands             0.0
23              Maryland          4045.0
24         Massachusetts         12500.0
25              Michigan         15718.0
26            Micronesia             0.0
27             Minnesota           986.0
28           Mississippi          1738.0
29              Missouri          2367.0
30               Montana           300.0
31              Nebraska           367.0
32                Nevada          1836.0
33         New Hampshire           669.0
34            New Jersey         37505.0
35            New Mexico           624.0
36              New York        119435.0
37        North Carolina          2870.0
38          North Dakota           207.0
39     Northern Marianas             8.0
40                  Ohio          4043.0
41              Oklahoma          1250.0
42                Oregon          1068.0
43                 Palau             0.0
44          Pennsylvania         11510.0
45           Puerto Rico           475.0
46          Rhode Island           922.0
47        South Carolina          2049.0
48          South Dakota           240.0
49             Tennessee          3633.0
50                 Texas          6812.0
51                  Utah          1605.0
52               Vermont           512.0
53        Virgin Islands            42.0
54              Virginia          2878.0
55            Washington          6973.0
56         West Virginia           324.0
57             Wisconsin          2267.0
58               Wyoming           200.0
```

To find this (it's not always the case), but you want to go to the site, and right click and open `Inspect` (Dev Tools). Then you want to search in Network -> XHR. If it's empty/blank you may need to refresh/reload the page.

Then you need to search/investigate to see if the data you want is there. Which in this case, I did find it there (as you can see in the highlight part:

[image]

Once you find it, you can go to `Headers` to find the relevant info/parameters you'll need to fetch the data.

[image]

This can/will be different for other sites, some more complicated than this, and some sites won't work at all. But this is the general method.

Comment: chitown88, please teach me how to do what you did. How did you know the data I was looking for was a json file? Is there a document that teaches me your thought process? I know this is a broad question but I must know. Please give me any knowledge you can think of.

Comment: @wolf7687 I updated the solution so you can see. kindly accept the solution. thx

Comment: @wolf7687let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. I need to find a good clear web-scraping book. Thanks again for your help.